# In Corda, constructor parameter doesn't refer to a property error

Tags: corda

I have defined the following interface:

```
open class IsBustCommand(val bustParty: Party, val isBust: Boolean)
```

And the following command:

```
interface Commands : CommandData {
    class GoToDirect(party: Party, isBust: Boolean) : IsBustCommand(party, isBust), Commands
}
```

When I run a flow, it throws:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: Constructor parameter - "party" - 
>   doesn't refer to a property of "class
>   com.cordacodeclub.directAgreement.contract.DirectAgreementContract$Commands$GoToDirect"
>   -> class com.cordacodeclub.directAgreement.contract.DirectAgreementContract$Commands$GoToDirect
>       at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SchemaKt.fingerprintForType(Schema.kt:438)
>   ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SchemaKt.fingerprintForType$default(Schema.kt:352)
>   ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]

If I change the parameter name in the constructor to:

````
class GoToDirect(bustParty: Party, isBust: Boolean) : IsBustCommand(bustParty, isBust), Commands```
````

Then I no longer receive an exception. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The Corda serialisation framework requires each constructor parameter to correspond to a property of the class of the same name.

In the first example, `party` is not a property of `GoToDirect` or its super-classes/interfaces, so this condition fails (you could fix this by adding a `val` to the constructor as follows: `class GoToDirect(val party: Party, isBust: Boolean)`).

In the second example, `bustParty` is not a property of `GoToDirect`, but it is a property of `IsBustCommand`, so this condition is met and serialisation succeeds.